# Why won't my iframe app appear when added to a page?

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs, facebook-iframe

I am trying to make a simple iframe app. The app works fine when navigating directly to it:

http://apps.facebook.com/meganliz

...however, when I try to add it to a page, it does not work; there is only white space where the app should be.

I have tried switching between http and https for the Canvas URL & Page Tab URL; it makes no difference.

To get the app to the page, I am using https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP_ID&next=https://apps.facebook.com/meganliz/ (replacing "APP_ID" with the actual app id)

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Jon

Answer (score 1):

Canvas url and Page tab url should be your server address from where your app should be loaded. You can have different content for both.

For example:

Canvas url: http://myserver.com/myapp/canvas_content/

Page tab url: http://myserver.com/myapp/page_tab_content/

To add the tab to your page try this:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL

Replace YOUR_URL with the value you entered in Page tab URL (http:myserver.com/myapp/page_tab_content/).

Comment: Ahh, that's it! I actually did have the Canvas URL and Page Tab URL different, but I tried making them the same and it worked! THANK YOU!!!!  -Jon